# Can't create multiple private BLE services on RN4020 Bluetooth module

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm trying to use Microchip's RN4020 Bluetooth Low Energy module to create my own custom services so I could control them from my phone.

When I try to create only one private service everything works just fine. The problem starts if I try to create more than 1 using the following commands

[image]

From all the `AOK` messages looks like there are no problems but when
i actually list all the available services with `LS` command

[image]

both characteristics are put under the 2nd service and 1st one don't even exist anymore. I tried to set one service at 1st, than reboot and than add another one but it made no difference.

Is there even a way to create more than 1 private service on this RN4020 BLE module?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi etrusks I guess by now you might have the answer for this issue. But for those who have the same issue.

It looks like RN4020 module has this issue and its not solved yet (firmware V1.23). microchip has addressed this issue in the "[RN4020 Bluetooth® Low Energy Module User’s Guide](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/70005191B.pdf)" They have a work around for this and you can read more about it in the same document.

Thank you!

Comment: Tnx for the answer man! Do you mean `PF,<UUID><Z>` command is a workaround for this problem?

Comment: Yes, that works perfectly when rn4020 connected to rn4020, also even though LS doesn’t list the services phone(or client) will be able to see services